# How to complete border length in javafx?

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I'm  working on a JavaFx application with CSS. I want the line of the box to fill all the space.

I have the following CSS.

```css
.box
{
    -fx-border-color:#000 #ff0000 #00ff00 #0000ff;
    -fx-border-width:5px;
}
```

This gives the result:

[image]

I want the black line to cover all the part of the top. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a "nested backgrounds" technique for your borders:

```css
.box {

    -fx-background-color: #000, #f00, #00f, #0f0, -fx-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 5 0 0 0, 5 5 0 0, 5 5 0 5, 5 ;
}
```

The way this works is that it draws five backgrounds, one on top of the other, with different insets for each. So first it draws a black background filling the whole pane; then it draws a red background filling the whole pane except 5 pixels at the top; then a blue background filling everything except five pixels at the top and at the right, etc.

With a little thought, you can control this quite finely. For example, changing it to

```css
.box {
    -fx-background-color: #000, #0f0, #f00, #00f, -fx-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 5 0 0 0, 5 0 5 0, 5 0 5 5, 5 ;
}
```

will let the green border span the entire width along the bottom, instead of letting the blue and red borders stretch all the way to the bottom of the pane.

Here's a quick test, with the code above in a file called `box-style.css`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BorderTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // just create a control so the default stylesheet is loaded:
        new Label();

        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getStyleClass().add("box");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("box-style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

With the first version of the CSS, this looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an ugly hack, but you could use multiple borders to simply draw the top border over the old border

```css
.box
{
    -fx-border-color: #000 #ff0000 #00ff00 #0000ff, #000;
    -fx-border-width: 5px, 5px 0 0 0;
}
```